# Flutter web image copy and paste

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web, dart-html

I need to implement a feature on flutter web, where if someone copies an image by pressing `crtl+c` and pastes it in a `TextField` using `ctrl+v` the image should pop-up and from there submit it to the database.

My question is how can I go about doing this? Is there a way to make it work with `ctrl+v` rather than a button.

Answer (score 3):

> is there a way to make it work with ctrl v rather than a button.

Yes there is, In flutter `Shortcuts` are handled with a `Shortcuts` Widget, along with this widget you'll also need to define an set of `Action`s and an `Intent` ( Not the same as Android Intent).

The `Intent` is where you will handle the actual logic of your action, do check the docs linked below as the exact way these classes mix together is not straight-forward.

This action is going complicated so lets work it though step-by-step if you need more help.

[Flutter docs for Shortcuts](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Shortcuts-class.html)